# why can I write over a piece of memory which has been allocated 0 space?

Tags: c

Why is it that I allocate a space of size 0 to array but i can still write over that piece of memory?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   int * array = malloc((sizeof(int)) * 0);
   int i;
   for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      array[i] = i;

   for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      printf("%d ", array[i]);
}
```

Comment: You invoked *undefined behaviour* and were unlucky not to get an obvious failure. C won't stop you from writing out of bounds.

Comment: For extra clarity, even when you allocate more than 0 bytes, C won't stop you from writing out of bounds. You, as a programmer, have to make sure to keep in bounds. With a bit of luck you will run into a segmentation fault. It will happen sooner or later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You code invokes *undefined behaviour* as you access index out of bounds -

```
 for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
 array[i] = i;
```

You won't get any warning or error about such thing but this is documented in standards that it is **UB**.

And in that case output could be anything.

And for this line -

```
int * array = malloc((sizeof(int)) * 0);
```

C Standard says -

> If the size of the space requested is zero, the behavior is implementation-defined: either a null pointer is returned, or the behavior is as if the size were some nonzero value, except that the returned pointer shall not be used to access an object.

Here it's return may or may not be `NULL pointer`. But it is clear that this pointer should not be used to access any object.

Comment: I understand that if i use a for loop trying to repeatedly allocate memory then the program will abort after the first iteration. But really how much memory does malloc give us?

Comment: @lplouis: malloc allocates the requested `size` bytes of memory. If the allocation succeeds, a pointer to the block of memory is returned, otherwise a NULL pointer is returned.

Comment: @Iplouis Please see the edit. And in general case `malloc`  will allocate requested size. On success pointer to that block is returned else NULL pointer.

Comment: @Jite "What can be said is that you don't get a NULL pointer or your program would have crashed"  is not supported by the C spec.  C does not specify that a program crashes when dereferencing `NULL`

Comment: @chux No sure, it's perfectly valid C to do so, however it's going to result in a run-time error (Access violation, Segfault etc) and crash on almost every modern system

Comment: @Jite Disagree with "almost every modern system".  At least 100s of millions of embedded processors made each year would not crash.

Comment: @chux I classified low level embedded as one type of system although they are many in practice. My impression is that most people asking questions here are asking from a deskop perspective or semi-embedded like RPi unless specified otherwise. But sure, this is SO, never assume anything, so I deleted the post.

Answer (score 2):

`malloc` with an argument of `0` returns either `NULL` or a unique pointer that can be passed to `free`.
If it does return a non-null value and that pointer points to memory that's within a page that's valid for your program and writable, the operating system won't zap you if you try to write to it, but you might end up rewriting some  parts of your program's data (=> undefined behavior).

Answer (score 0):

C is an **unsafe language**. as an **unsafe language** it allows you to do risky actions as the following:

- Writing/Reading to/from unallocated memory.
- Implicity casting types (`void*` to other types and vica versa).
- No bound checks.
- Memory is `Unmanaged`.
- Etc...

Since those actions are risky and might lead to `Memory Leak`, `Memory Corruption` and other unwanted results, you should avoid doing such things when they are not neccesary and keep clean and conventioned code (make this `10` a **constant** and avoid working on **unallocated memory**).

Comment: I think is enough safe. The programmer make it unsafe if he has no idea of what he's doing.

Comment: Of course that if you are being careful and know what you are doing you are fine, but relatively the place for error is bigger than in C++ and much bigger than in managed languages like C#. I never told him not to use C.